# Parse error while running a simple Haskell program

Tags: haskell

I have just started learning Haskell. I'm beginning by writing a simple function that takes two values n and x, and then displays two integer values computed with it.

```
test n x = do
    cell1 = round(n*n*x)
    cell2 = n*n - cell1
    print cell1
    print cell2
```

But it doesn't run and keeps giving me a *Parse error on input `='* error. What is happening?

Comment: `let cell1 = ...` instead of `cell1 = ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You've hit your first trouble with Monads.  What you probably want here is a `let` statement inside your `do` block

```
test n x = do
    let cell1 = round (n * n * x)
        cell2 = n * n - cell1
    print cell1
    print cell2
```

The difference here is that you can't assign directly inside of a `do` block, since all `do` blocks desugar to calls to `>>=` and `>>`.  The `let` statement allows you to define a local value like you can inside a function definition like

```
f x =
    let y = 2 * x
        z = y * y * y
    in z + z + y
```

The way your function would desugar would be like

```
test n x =
    let cell1 = round (n * n * x)
        cell2 = n * n - cell1
    in (print cell1 >> print cell2)
```

Where `>>` just chains two monadic actions together.  Note that this is not really how it desugars, I chose a representation that is equivalent in this case but it is not exactly what the compiler would actually generate.

Comment: Apart from a redundant set of parentheses it *is* exactly the official desugaring from the [language report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14). Of course the compiler won't stop at that stage...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I had just assumed that it might have been something a bit different, since `let` bindings can use values extracted from monadic actions (`do { x <- m; let y = f x; return y }`, for example).

Comment: Okay, then how do I call the function in the command line? Like I run the program file, then do I just do: test 2 0.4? Because this doesn't return me any result.

Comment: @EricaMaine Are you wanting to compile it or load it in GHCi?  And this function won't return anything because you haven't told it to, you've only told it to print those values.

Comment: And I get this error: No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from the literal ‘0.4’

Comment: @bheklilr: Ya, I meant, on the command line I want to print the values, so I was writing test 2 0.4, but I didn't print anything.

Comment: @EricaMaine The problems that you're having with your code are simple to solve, but would take more words than can fit in a comment box.  I would encourage you to post a new question so that you can paste your code and the full text of the error messages you're seeing, and because what you're asking is a different question entirely than the one asked above.  I will give you the hint that your problem will require some manual type conversions and you would have caught the problem earlier had you given you `test` function an explicit type signature.