# How to use the Random Package for mapping the result to specific values in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I just began learning Haskell, and I'm writing my first code. What I am doing in this is writing a function that takes two arguments returns a list of lists of integer, where each list is of length n ( forming an n x n grid), and each integer has probability p of having having a value, (1-p) of being empty (no value). I want to use the encoding 0 = empty, 1 = value.

```
test :: Int -> Float -> [[Int]]    
test n p = do
          let values = round(n*n*p)
              noValues = n*n - values
          print values
          print noValues

    main = do
         test 4 0.4
```

The values variable will give us the number of elements in the grid which will have a value, and noValues will give us the number that will be empty. Now, how do I decide which cells will have a value and which will not?
I was planning to use the random package like:

```
import System.Random
g <- getStdGen
take n (randoms g :: [Double])
```

Which gives me a list with floating values, but I don't understand how can I apply this to my problem, i.e., how to make it into a list of lists, and then map it with values 0 and 1?

Comment: The type signature of `test` looks quite wrong. You print something inside, so `test` should return `IO something`. Also, you do not return any `[[Int]]`. If you are starting Haskell, this exercise may be too complex for the moment, since it involves IO, randomness, monads, and lists. I would recommend you start from something simpler, e.g. trying to follow [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: @chi this is actually a homework question, someone else from what seems to be the same class asked the same thing this morning :)

Comment: @alternative Actually I only asked it this morning too. But, you can read in the comments that I was advised to put up a new question here, since I had more doubts regarding it. :)

Comment: @Erica Maine I don't think it was you who asked it this morning unless you have two accounts on SO

Comment: @alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678028/parse-error-while-running-a-simple-haskell-program/26678210?noredirect=1#comment41963723_26678210 :)

Comment: @EricaMaine I was actually referring to the very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690118/how-to-append-random-number-to-a-list/26690148#comment41977376_26690148 (with the exact same question asked in a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `randoms` to generate a list of `Double` in the range (0, 1) of the required length, then map the resulting values to your element type if it meets the given threshold `p`. Then you need to convert the one-dimensional list into a two-dimensional grid e.g.

```
genElements :: (RandomGen g) => g -> Float -> Int -> [[Int]]
genElements r p n = mkGrid $ map (\d -> if d <= p then 1 else 0) $ take (n*n) (randoms r)
  where mkGrid r = unfoldr nextRow (r, n)
        nextRow (_, 0) = Nothing
        nextRow (es, i) = let (r, rest) = splitAt n es in Just (r, (rest, i-1))
```

You can then pass the random generator you want such as `StdGen`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- getStdGen
  let g = genElements gen 0.3 3
  print g
```

Comment: I tried doing what you told, but I get some errors. I edited my question to put the error, could you tell me what it means?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you can make a function like `genValue :: Float -> IO Int` which takes `p` as the parameter and gives a random indicator.

Then you can generate the grid like

```
 grid :: Int -> Float -> IO [[Int]]
 grid n = replicateM n . replicateM n . genValue
```